# %sessionname% returns incorrect session name

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, environment-variables

I have a virtualised Windows XP SP3 machine, which I am connecting to over Remote Desktop.
One of my scripts needs to use the %sessionname% variable. However this returns incorrect information.

```
C:\>%sessionname%
```

constantly returns RDP-Tcp#5, instead of the value for the currently connected session (RDP-Tcp#35 or similar), as shown in Task Manager

This causes my scripts to contain incorrect information. What can I do to resolve this?

Edit Further Information: A restart appears to solve the problem for the first connection, but then subsequent connections have the numbers fall out of sync again.

Comment: are you trying to run this as a local user or a domain user (assuming you have a domain)?

Comment: local user, there is no domain configured on these machines.

Comment: Adding Further information, a restart appears to correct the problem, but only for the first reconnection. The numbers then get out of sync again.

Comment: I've put in a workaround for the moment, but I'm still concerned as to why this variable is incorrect most of the time.

Comment: Does `qwinsta /server:servername` work? If sessions are constantly changing this may assist in determining the new sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I am having exactly the same problem with Windows Server 2008 R2 running as a Remote Desktop. Session ID seems to be always correct but you cannot get Session ID from either %sessionid% or  from with VBA Environ("SessionID"). My workaround is to use Environ("UserName") with C:>query session to extract the SessionID then use that with C:>query process "processname" to determine if the process is running in the session. I am not sure what your script is doing but perhaps this approach will help. Please note that this will only work if a user is only allowed one session at a time as is the case in our terminal server setup. If a user can have more than one session then the sessionid will not be unique based on username.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it doesn't update properly, but perhaps you can use the ouput of [query session](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ts_cmd_querysession.mspx) instead? It's a bit more detailed as well.

Comment: Hmm...
    C:\>query session
Fails, query is not recognized.

This happens on all our of XP VM's. I suspect there may be a deeper issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul for your post. I have the same issue on Win2008R2 and I changed my script to this :

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%f in (`query session ^| findstr /C:^^^>`) do set session="%%f"
set session=%session:~10,-1%
tasklist /FI "SESSIONNAME eq RDP-Tcp#%session%" | findstr mytool.exe >NUL
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 echo Tool found!
```

I look for the current session (so it works if several sessions are opened with the same user). Then I look if my tool is running in the current session.
Note the " " around %%f so that I am not annoyed by the ">" at the beginning of the line.